# C# WPF 2 запроса на одну кнопку

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу программу для включения и выключения реле на плате. На плате 16 реле и 32 команды, есть ComboBox с 16 реле и кнопка ON/OFF. Суть в том, когда отправляешь запрос на 1 реле оно включалось а при еще одном нажатии - выключалось. 00 - Реле 1 Включено, 01 - выключено, 02 - Реле 2 включено, 03 - реле 2 выключено, как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Может быть надо иметь массив из 16 булевых значений и при нажатии кнопки брать из массива элемент с индексом как SelectedIndex у комбобокса и менять значение на противоположное и отправлять на плату это текущее значение?

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю как управлять реле, но вот довольно примитивная схема кнопки, которая перенаправляется от нажатия.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static public int butt = 0;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
    }

   

    private void bbb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            if (butt == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Режим 1");
                butt = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (butt == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Режим 2");
                butt = 0;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
}
```

Ничего не нажато
[image: Ничего не нажато]
Кнопка нажата 1-й раз
[image: Кнопка нажата 1-й раз]
Кнопка нажата 2-й раз
[image: Кнопка нажата 2-й раз]
Кнопка нажата 3-й раз
[image: Кнопка нажата 3-1 раз]

Надеюсь, что поможет

Comment: Какой-то бред. Не, код может и рабочий, но зачем у `butt` стоит `public`, да еще и `static`? Далее, зачем там цикл `for`, этого хоть убейте, понять не могу. Хорошо, другой вопрос, зачем тут вообще `butt`? Ведь в WPF есть `ToggleButton`, которая имеет весь этот функционал, берете просто `IsChecked` и делаете что хотите. Заметьте, я еще молчу про неотъемлемую часть WPF - привязки. Хорошо, ну и последнее - у автора много объектов, которые должны менять состояния, у него вопрос не "как сделать ToggleButton", как ваш ответ отвечает на поставленную задачу?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я еще далеко не профи. Захотел помочь, попытался разобраться. И вот на сколько пока мозгов хватило

Comment: Я понимаю, что вы не профи, по этому не влепил минус и не голосовал за удаление, лишь указал вам ваши ошибки. Ну и сам вопрос, прочтите его внимательней: "16 значений в ComboBox, при нажатие на кнопку надо отправлять команду включения/выключения, где для первого значения это будет 00/01 (вкл/выкл), для второго 02/03 и так для всех 16-ти." А вы человеку просто говорите как сделать кнопку, да еще и весьма странными методами. Так отвечает ли это на поставленную задачу, хоть немного?